# How to avoid apache content spoofing

Tags: php, apache, security

I need to avoid content spoofing or user input injection on my based web application. Right now If I access an non-existent file or URL I'll see my custom 404 page but if for example I access to a existent file but add additional parameters like this:

```
http://example.com/crossdomain.xml/%20is%20not%20available.%20Go%20to%20www.otherpage.com
```

I see apache's default 404 page with the content injected to it instead my custom 404 page, like the following image

[image]

How can I setup apache to handle this?

Comment: I don't know if this can be done or not. But the question is why? This will only affect the visitor that uses such an URL. It's client side. It's the same as with Greasemonkey for example. I can inject additional client side Javascript into websites. But it will only affect me. It won't affect anyone else.

Comment: I've been advertised that this can open a content spoofing security risk so is mandatory to fix it.

In the past I've used AllowEncodedSlashes On to fix a similar issue but this time that didn't help

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a custom 404 in your Apache conf file:

ErrorDocument 404 /custom_404.html

Ref: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59772